# Хранение данных в session или cookies

Tags: php, pdo

При авторизации я записываю логин в сессию. У меня в БД есть столбец с числами от 0 включительно. Проверку того какое число у определенного пользователя - я делаю следующим образом:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT day_today FROM users WHERE login = (:login) ");
$stmt->bindParam(':login', $_SESSION['login']); // ?
$stmt->execute();
```

Но я где-то краем глаза видел, что длительность сессии = 15 минутам. Отсюда 2 вопроса - действительно ли это так? И если это так и через $_SESSION['login'] - это не надёжный способ выбора логина пользователя, который сейчас авторизован - то как мне выбрать его логин иначе?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-cache-expire.php

Comment: По умолчанию время жизни сессии 15 минут. Но это легко меняется [тык] (https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=php-session). По поводу логина - зачем тебе индексы в таблице, пиши индекс пользователя в сессию.